# Shopping Cart Promotions in Magento Admi not showing

Tags: magento

I seem to have a problem on my backend in magento, im running 1.7 and the shopping cart promotions work, however after i save it, it doesn't display it in the backend, and i cant edit it or anything.

any ideas what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

My first advice would be to flush cache, perhaps clear /var and /session manually. log out and back in and try again. Usually works for me.